# Pass parameter with custom POST link

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There's a question page with several answer variants to choose from. Clicking on a variant link/button should create an answer and associate it with the question and the variant.

I've added this action in the `questions_controller.rb`:

```
  def select_variant
    @question = Question.find(params[:id])
    variant = Variant.find(params[:id])
    Answer.create(question: @question, variant: variant)
    redirect_to question_path(@question),
    notice: "Question was successfully answered."
  end
```

The route

```
 resources :questions do
    member do
      post :select_variant, to: "questions#select_variant"
    end
  end
```

And the POST link in the question show view.

```
<% @question.variants.each do |variant| %>
  <%= link_to variant.body, select_variant_question_path(@question, variant), method: :post %>
<% end %>
```

How can I pass the correct variant ID along with the link because at the moment it just duplicates the question ID?

```
Answer Create (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "answers" ("question_id", "created_at", "updated_at", "variant_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["question_id", 1], ["created_at", "2021-03-03 15:05:15.236787"], ["updated_at", "2021-03-03 15:05:15.236787"], ["variant_id", 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you want to set a different route in your `routes.rb`.

```
 post 'select_variant/:question_id/:variant_id', to: "questions#select_variant"
```

With that, in your controller, you just call the params by:

```
 @question = Question.find(params[:question_id])
 variant = Variant.find(params[:variant_id])
```

Comment: OP's route makes a little more sense, I think: `questions/:id/select_variant`, **except** (!!) as you say, it's missing a variant ID. Maybe it could be: `questions/:id/select_variant/:variant_id`. Anyway, whatever, that's just personal preference...

Comment: @Carlo, can you please elaborate so that I could understand what's wrong with the original implementation and how your suggestion fixes it? So far your suggestion doesn't work so can you also add URL options for the link.

Comment: The thing is, when sending parameters in a link, even if it has the post method, inside the route, you must provide the parameters that are expected in the URL,
because there is no form submitted with the link, what you say to the route, is that you are sending two parameters. That is why when sending parameters like this, they are added in the route, in the order in which you are sending it.
 post 'select_variant/:question_id/:variant_id', to: "questions#select_variant", in this your are sending two parameters with names question_id and variant_id.

Comment: @CarloOsores Thanks. What URL would that route generate? It doesn't seem to work. Also, do you know what @TomLord means when he says that adding or not adding `:variant_id` to the route is just a matter of preference?

Comment: @inmydelorean My suggestion is a slightly different route structure, and slightly differently named parameters. For example, you may have a  `QuestionsController#show` that's expecting an `id` parameter for the question -- so likewise, for consistency, I'd opt to have a `QuestionsController#show_variant` what's also expecting an `id` parameter for the question (and a `variant_id` parameter for the variant).

Comment: Nothing about the answer above is wrong; I'm just stating a personal preference for what I would consider to be more rational/standardised/consistent naming in the route.

Comment: @TomLord, thanks. You are right with that, it is more rational/standardised/consistent naming in the route. I Forgot about talking about best practices.